# Edit css before <br> but not using ::first-line

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to edit the CSS of a line before a `<br>` not using `::first-line`?

Specifically, in my code, I would like the first phrase ("Reach your ideal clients") to be bolded; however, at a certain screen size, part of the line gets shifted to the next line so the `::first-line` indication doesn't seem to do the trick.

(I unfortunately can't change the HTML since I'm using a third party platform)

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yuyutomi/rsnod0zg/

```css
.desc-wrapper p:first-line {
  font-weight: 800;
}
.desc-wrapper p {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-wrapper" data-content-field="description">
  <p>I would always like to be bold
    <br>I would like to be normal font-weight</p>
  <p>I'm a placeholder</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have chance to use jQuery?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want with just CSS as you would need the HTML structure to change a little bit. You could however use `Jquery`.

Comment: Why not just put the specific part inside a `span` and not bother with this kind of trickery? Seems to me like a classic xy-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not with css. but you can use simple Jquery code.

Here is your fiddle with [example](https://jsfiddle.net/rsnod0zg/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var getContent=$(".desc-wrapper").html();
var newString=getContent.replace('Reach your ideal clients','<span class="YourClass">Reach your ideal clients</span>');
$(".desc-wrapper").html(newString);
});
```

```css
.YourClass {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.desc-wrapper p {
  font-size: 46px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
  font-weight: 100; 
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 58px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc-wrapper" data-content-field="description">
  <p> Reach your ideal clients<br>Shape your dream practice </p>
  <p>Do more of what you love</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way similar to Guitaro's but without Jquery

```js
var selector = document.querySelectorAll(".desc-wrapper p");

for (let i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
  var getContent = selector[i].innerHTML;
  var getContentSplit = getContent.split("<br>");
  if (!(getContentSplit.length <= 1)) {
    selector[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + getContentSplit[0] + "</b>";
    for (let j = 1; j < getContentSplit.length; j++) {
      selector[i].innerHTML += "<br>" + getContentSplit[j];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.desc-wrapper p {
  font-size: 46px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 58px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-wrapper" data-content-field="description">
  <p>I would always like to be bold
    <br>I would like to be normal font-weight</p>
  <p>I'm a placeholder</p>
  <p>I would always like to be bold
    <br>I would like to be normal font-weight
    <br>I would like to be normal font-weight</p>
</div>
```